# How can I simulate a visit in a website like I was in web browser

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to find if there is a way to simulate a visit in a website like I was in web browser, with javascript execution etc...

If I try like with jsdom, google analytics shows me nothing for my personnel website. It's only capture source code.

How can I do that with node.js ?

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by simulate? When a web browser visits a website, it makes an http request to the server, and if the server returns an html document, it parses and shows it to you. You could do an http request using Node.js [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) module (example taken directly from docs):

```
http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // Consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
      console.log(parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

Comment: Some javascript are loaded when we visit a website. If I make a simple http request every javascript called in this page are not executed. That's why i'm talking about "simulate". Sorry for my english.

Comment: You could try to use something like this: https://github.com/assaf/zombie